# Why is there a performance diffrence between running two separate loops vs single for-loop in js

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

i ran this code on the my server an i noticed there is a performance difference between running two separate loops vs single for-loop can someone explain why ?

```
for(let k=0;k<100000000;k++) {
    let s = Date.now();
    for(let i=0;i<1e9;i++) { i + 100 }
    for(let i=0;i<1e9;i++) { i + 100 }
    let s1 = Date.now() - s;

    s = Date.now();
    for(let i=0;i<2e9;i++) { i + 100 }
    let s2 = Date.now() - s;

    console.log(s1, s2 , s1 - s2)
}
```

these are my results in json: https://pastebin.com/bRqku0zJ

Comment: Wild guess, is V8 smart enough to see two identical loops with no side-effects, and (eventually) effectively run only one?

Comment: When i run your code in the console of chrome on my computer (having reduced the k max value to 20...), the difference between the two counters is very small and s1(670 on avg) is longer than s2 (655 on avg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the question in dev2 also. Thanks to *da-ti*. 
https://dev.to/dati/comment/eii1

> This has nothing to do with JIT compiler, loops, multi-threading or BigInt. If this was a some quiz question it would test:
>   -Understating that every number in js implicitly is floating point number
>   -Knowing how floating point addition works and that (unlike addition of integers) it takes multiple hw level operations
>
> [Addition_and_subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Addition_and_subtraction)
>
> To make this test fair for both one loop variant and two loops
>   variant:
>
> ```
>  s = Date.now() 
>  for(let i=0;i<1e10;i++) { i + 100 } 
>  for(let i=1e10;i<2e10;i++) { i + 100 } 
>  console.log(Date.now() - s)
>
>  s = Date.now() for(let i=0;i<2e10;i++) { i + 100 }
>  console.log(Date.now() - s)
> ```
>
> Now both variants work with exact same numbers and perform exact same
>   floating point operations (time diff is consistently <20ms on my
>   machine now, where it was 500-1500ms before)
>
> TLDR: floating point